# MQTT: Send a message on graceful disconnect

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto

Last Will and Testament (LWT) is only sent when an ungraceful disconnect happens, I want to send a message on every client disconnect.

I have a mobile application in which I want to show the online status of the user, I am planning on showing publishing every few seconds to a topic say `online` with the user identification to which the server will be subscribed and keep the online status of the client updated.

LWT is only in cases of ungraceful disconnect. So if I am using that to check the state of my client's online status then there are chances that the client goes offline with a graceful exit and the backend never gets to know about it.

Is there any way to solve this issue with MQTT?

I can keep the last-active of the client in the database and check the online status with a query, but I wanted to achieve this with only MQTT, if possible.

Note: I am using Mosquitto MQTT

Comment: How about announcing your intention to disconnect before disconnecting?   If the disconnection is originated server-side, you likely have other problems to deal with.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, can you point me to the right location?

Comment: Insert a publish operation into your code before the disconnect operation.   Or else explain how your connection is experiencing "graceful" but "unplanned" disconnection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This has cleared things. 

I have one more question - if the client is connected with the broker and the conncetion times out and the reconnects (everthing happens automatically without any forced connection closing) will I get the Last Will?